# invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' )

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino

I'm trying to wrap arduino's RF24 functions into a simpler class that I could use more intuitively in the future, so I have made a .h file:

```
#ifndef RADIO_H
#define RADIO_H

#include <RF24.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

class Radio
{
    private:
        RF24 radio(int ce, int csn);
        int opMode;
        byte address;

    protected:
        void setReceiver();
        void setTransmitter();
    
    public:
        Radio(int ce, int csn, int mode, byte channel); 
};
 #endif
```

and a .cpp file:

```
#include "Radio.h"
#include "Parameters.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>


Radio::Radio(int ce, int csn, int mode, byte channel){
    RF24 radio(ce,csn);
  radio.begin();
  opMode = mode;
    address = channel;
    
    if(opMode == RX){
        setReceiver();
    }
    else if(opMode == TX){
        setTransmitter();
    }
}

//Protected Functions
void Radio::setReceiver(){
    //radio.openReadingPipe(0,address);
    //radio.startListening();
  
}

void Radio::setTransmitter(){
    //radio.openWritingPipe(address);
    radio.stopListening();
}
```

However, I'm receiving the following error and can't figure out what's wrong with the code:

> sketch\Radio.cpp: In member function 'void Radio::setTransmitter()':
> Radio.cpp:74:2: error: invalid use of member function 'RF24
> Radio::radio(int, int)' (did you forget the '()' ?)
> radio.stopListening();   ^~~~~ Radio.cpp:74:2: error: invalid use of
> member function 'RF24 Radio::radio(int, int)' (did you forget the '()'
> ?) exit status 1 invalid use of member function 'RF24
> Radio::radio(int, int)' (did you forget the '()' ?)

can anyone help me figure out what went wrong?

Comment: In your constructor, you have `RF24 radio(ce,csn);`.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: trying to set up an object of the type RF24 (which takes in 2 integers). the function stopListening is a member function of RF24

Comment: That `RF24` instance (had it been one) would be destroyed at the end of the constructor. You should probably make it a member variable instead.

Comment: `RF24 radio(int ce, int csn);` in the class definition looks like it's supposed to be a member variable but is actually a member function definition.

Comment: `RF24 radio(int ce, int csn);` -- What does your C++ book say how to declare member variables?  That is not a member variable declaration, that is a function declaration.  Then after that, what does your C++ book say about things such as member-initialization lists?

Comment: how can I retain it to reference later in the code? the idea behind the class is to wrap RF24 so that I could use its member functions "behind the scenes" when I set up an object of Radio class (so that when I create a radio object it would automatically perform the relevant RF24 functions that are used to set up the radio as either a receiver or a transmitter)

Comment: Not sure if this is a case of the *most* vexing parse but it's certainly a candidate for *quite* vexing parse! Try changing `RF24 radio(ce,csn);` to `RF24 radio{ce,csn};`. But it depends a lot on what the definition of `RF24` is.

Comment: @AdrianMole in the class definition it is `RF24 radio(int ce, int csn);`, that defines a method without doubt (and thats what causes the error in `setTransmitter`, the line in the constructor is secondary)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 OK - just spotted that. So, it's a *not really* vexing parse. :-)

Comment: @LahavBarak -- The issue is we do not know what your intent is here: `RF24 radio(int ce, int csn)`.  So are you trying to declare a member variable, or declare a function called `radio` that returns an `RF24` that takes two `int` arguments?

Comment: @NathanPierson problem is, when I try to change that line into RF24 radio; I get the error  "No matching function for call to RF24::RF24()" with the line "Radio::Radio(int ce, int csn, int mode, byte channel){" in .cpp file marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an instance of `RF24` called `radio` but you've declared a function called `radio` that returns an `RF24` instance:

```
class Radio
{
private:
    RF24 radio; // remove: (int ce, int csn);
    ...
```

Then in your constructor, initialize it like this:

```
Radio::Radio(int ce, int csn, int mode, byte channel)
    :              // colon starts the member initializer list
    radio(ce, csn) // initialize the radio
{
    ...
```

Comment: Worked. didn't know the thing about the colon initialization, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a member function `radio` that takes two `int`s and returns a `RF24`.

Declare `radio` as a member variable in the same way as other member variables,

```
RF24 radio;
```

and initialize it in the initializer list,

```
Radio::Radio(int ce, int csn, int mode, byte channel)
    : radio(ce, csn)
{
    radio.begin();
    // ...
```